# configure qmake for install headers to different subfolders

Tags: qt, qmake, nmake

I have project where header files are in different subfolders (/config/*.h; /thread/*.h etc)
in qt project file they are included like:

```
HEADERS += $$PWD/src/*.h
HEADERS += $$PWD/src/config/*.h
```

then install is described as simple:

```
headers.files = $$HEADERS
headers.path  = $$INSTALL_INC_DIR/proj
```

some other projects that use this lib will include files from that install dir and there problem occurs - all .h files are copied to same folder, without subfolders and in code they are included with subfolders (`#include <proj/config/config.h>`).

Is it possible to tell qmake (or actually nmake) that when copying files keep original folder stucture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

headerinstall.pri:

```
for(header, INSTALL_HEADERS) {
  path = $${INSTALL_PREFIX}/$${dirname(header)}
  eval(headers_$${path}.files += $$header)
  eval(headers_$${path}.path = $$path)
  eval(INSTALLS *= headers_$${path})
}
```

at the end of your .pro file:

```
INSTALL_PREFIX = /tmp/installprefix
INSTALL_HEADERS = $$HEADERS
include(headerinstall.pri)
```

Comment: it was a bit long ago, but I will accept answer. And try, maybe it will be useful now as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, that the currently accepted answer from 2013 was valid for the time being.
However, it did not work well for me with all the slashes and dots and colons in the `$${path}`. Also we have to put `$$list()` around a list of files nowadays to use it in a for loop.

Here is the approach I came up with. I wrote that in a `*.pri` file and added it to my directory structure. No need for the extra `INSTALL_HEADERS` variable:

```
for(header, $$list($$HEADERS)) {
  path = $$OUT_PWD/../include/$$dirname(header)
  pathname = $$replace(path,/,)
  pathname = $$replace(pathname,\.,)
  pathname = $$replace(pathname,:,)
  file = headers_$${pathname}
  eval($${file}.files += $$header)
  eval($${file}.path = $$path)
  INSTALLS *= $${file}
}
```

Note that the replacement characters may vary for you. For example, my first approach above had still problems with whitespaces in the path, so I added:

`pathname = $$replace(pathname," ",)`